# Geometry Nodes instance child objects?

Tags: node-editor, geometry

In Geometry Modes (Blender 3), when instancing objects. How can I also instance their child objects too?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about dragging a object and all its children into instances, BUT if you want to instance a series of objects, you can do it with collections. Add all your objects into a collection, then drag that collection to your node setup like so:

[image]

It will automatically create a **Collection Info** node and populate it with the required collection. I believe you also need to check the boxes next to *Separate Children, Reset Children* and *Pick Instance* if you want them all to be separately distributed objects but I'm not certain.

Hope that helps.